# SVA Signal doesn't change while other one is true

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

This is very basic but I've been blocked the whole afternoon.
I need a property to check that if A is set, B cannot change.

```
         _____________________
A ______/                     \______________
                                                   PASS
B ___________________________________________


         _____________________
A ______/                     \______________
                     ________________________      FAIL
B __________________/
```

I tried A |-> $stable(B) but that doesn't work

Any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

What you wrote says: "*every cycle that A is true, B must be stable in the same cycle*". That is a single-cycle assertion.

What you want is

```
$rose(A) |-> ##1 $stable(B) until !(A);
```

The `##1` is needed if you do not need the first cycle that A is true for B to be stable.

Comment: Thank you, it is a good solution, but don't ask me why, I can't use the until statement, from our SVA guidelines.

I found this other way to do it. This seems to do the work. I was very confused because the property failed without the !A and using |-> or |=> and Jasper didn't show me correctly the last cycle, I don't know why.

    A |=> $stable(B) | !A